# Insert 1 or 0 where EXCEPT returns a value when comparing tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, compare, sql-server-2014, except

Using SQL Server 2014, how can I return a table of 1's or 0's and then count the 1's where there is a match in like tables for multiple field names, grouping by [Loan Identifier]. I currently have a table called dbo.Tape which is the original table and then dbo.[Tape Capture] which users are updating. The [Loan Identifier] is identical in both tables.

Thanks if you can help.

```
SELECT       
   [Loan Identifier], [Completion date], [Tenure], [Underwriter name] 
FROM 
   dbo.Tape

EXCEPT

SELECT      
    [Loan Identifier], [Completion date], [Tenure], [Underwriter name]  
FROM 
    dbo.[Tape Capture]
```

If the `[Completion date]` in `dbo.Tape` matched the `[Completion date]` in `dbo.[Tape Capture]`, then I would like to return 1, else zero. Then I would like to sum all of these values in each column. For example,

**dbo.[Tape Capture]**:

```
[Loan Identifier], [Completion date], [Tenure], [Underwriter name] 
1                    01/01/2016       Freehold     James Mac
2                    01/01/2016       Leasehold    James Mac
3                    02/01/2016       Freehold     James Mac
4                    01/01/2016       Leasehold    James Mac
5                    03/01/2016       Freehold     James Mac
```

**dbo.Tape**:

```
[Loan Identifier], [Completion date], [Tenure], [Underwriter name] 
1                    01/01/2016       Freehold     James Mac
2                    01/01/2016       Freehold     James Mac
3                    01/01/2016       Freehold     James Mac
4                    01/01/2016       Freehold     James Mac
5                    01/01/2016       Freehold     James Mac
```

Then I would like the results table to hold:

```
[Loan Identifier], [Completion date], [Tenure], [Underwriter name] 
1                    1                  1          1
2                    1                  0          1
3                    0                  1          1
4                    1                  0          1
5                    0                  1          1
```

From here, I would like to sum up the values in each column.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help explain what you want to do.  It is entirely unclear what results you are looking for.

Comment: Hi Gordon, thanks. I have edited my question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT T.[Loan Identifier], 
       CASE 
         WHEN TC.[Completion date] = T.[Completion date] THEN 1 
         ELSE 0 
       END AS [Completion date], 
       CASE 
         WHEN TC.[Tenure] = T.[Tenure] THEN 1 
         ELSE 0 
       END AS [Tenure], 
       CASE 
         WHEN TC.[Underwriter name] = T.[Underwriter name] THEN 1 
         ELSE 0 
       END AS [Underwriter name] 
FROM   [dbo].[Tape] AS T 
       LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Tape Capture] AS TC 
              ON T.[Loan Identifier] = TC.[Loan Identifier]
```